Is there a way to determine the element that caused an input to lose focus, thus triggering a change event?
I basically want to know if the user clicked the button and that's what caused the input to lose focus, and as a result the change event to be triggered, or if it was triggered as a result of clicking somewhere else or tabbing away etc.
For context, I have a form with an autosave function, which is triggered with a change event. The issue is that if they click the Save button, it autosaves but I don't want it to. There are a number of ways I could prevent this, but the ideal way would simply be not to autosave if the change event was triggered when they clicked the Save button.
e.originalEvent is undefined in this case, so that doesn't help!
jsfiddle


document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "I want to know if this event handler was called because the user clicked on Button 1 or not"
});
#results {
  margin-top:10px;
}
<div><input id="text"></div>
<hr>
<button id="button1">
Button 1
</button>
<div id="results">

</div>




Does this answer your question? How can I check on which element the event was triggered?

@ChrisG - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "ready the log"? I just want to know whether the event was triggered from a click on the save button or not.

@devlincarnate - it does not. The target is the input with the change event attached to it, not the element that triggered the change event on the input

@BenHolness it was a typo, no the event was not triggered by the button click. Why would it? Your button is completely useless in this snippet, there is no logic attached to your button. Clicking on the button counts as clicking outside the input. Which is what triggers the event

@ChrisG - I understand that, I want to know in the logic attached to the change event if there's a way to tell what it was that the user clicked outside the input that triggered the event so that I can change the logic in the change event depending on whether the clicking outside the input was a click on the button or not.

If you want to know if the user clicked the button, bind a click event to it.   That change event on the input is triggered when the input loses focus.  The button has nothing to do with it.  You can see this by clicking the background instead of the button...it shows message that the event was triggered.  That's how the change event on input="text" works. according to the documentation.

@devlincarnate - I understand that, I want to know within the change event handler for the input whether focus was lost when the user clicked on the button or for another reason. Having logic in a click event on the button is not useful in my situation because the change event on the input was already called, so it's too late to stop it from doing its thing by then.

May not be the most elegant answer but one way to do that would be to track the button click with a variable and then use that in the change event listener. Adding a small timeout would ensure the button click variable is handled first.  Here is an example:


let button = false

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  button = true
});

document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(button ? "It was button" : "It was not the button")
    
    button = false
  }, 100)
});
<div><input id="text"></div>
<hr>
<button id="button1">
Button 1
</button>
<div id="results">
</div>




This is one of the alternative ways I have considered if it turns out I can't determine it directly. Thanks!

I don't know if this is a 100% backed idea, but you could add changes to an array and then decide to save or not to save on the click or focusin events (maybe more events need to be handeled). And saving could also be done in the submit event if needed.


var changeQueue = [];

document.addEventListener('focusin', e => {
  console.log('focusin');
  if (e.target !== document.getElementById('button1')) {
    save();
  }
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  changeQueue.push(e.target);
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('click');
  if (e.target !== document.getElementById('button1')) {
    save();
  }
});

function save() {
  if (changeQueue.length > 0) {
    // save the changes
    console.log('saving', changeQueue.map(elm => `value: ${elm.value}`).join(';'));
    changeQueue = [];
  }
}

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (changeQueue.length > 0) {
    console.log('There is something that needs saving');
    console.log('Submitting the form');
  }else{
    console.log('nothing to save');
  }
});
#results {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<form name="form01">
  <div><input id="text1"></div>
  <div><input id="text2"></div>
  <hr>
  <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>




This is an interesting approach, but unfortunately would mean a huge amount of refactoring in the actual setup I have - what I posted here was a very simplified setup to highlight the approach I was hoping to take, if it was possible. Thanks though!
